# instead of objectwidth = 1014; I want objectwidth = "Height of other div"; Possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Okay so have have 2 variables.

```
var canvasWidth = 1014;
var canvasHeight = 611;
```

The rest of the script animation uses these variables to calculate where the middle of the screen is- but thats not important.

Instead of giving the canvas width a "hard" width and height I would simply like it to get the width and height from the div its in.

I would like something like: `var canvasHeight = heightOf "#DIV1"`

However im too **new to javascript** to figure out what to put in.

How would it be written? Id *post the project* but its complex and working within a really messy CMS.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you provide some `HTML` and `CSS`?

Comment: Can you mark it as "solved" if the answer is correct for you ? Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var canvasHeight = document.getElementById("divID").clientHeight
```

in your case if the div has the ID "DIV1"

```
var canvasHeight = document.getElementById("DIV1").clientHeight
```

or with jQuery :

```
var canvasHeight = $("#DIV1").height();
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `canvas` is **always** supposed to have its `parent` element's height you should use `CSS`:

```
canvas {
    height: 100%;
}
```

If depending on the `height` or `width` of the `viewport` you might want to try `mediaquery`:

```
@media screen and (min-width: ...px) {
    canvas {
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

or

```
@media screen and (max-width: ...px) {
    canvas {
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

I wouldn't use `JS` if it can be done with `CSS`.

Comment: I am asking for a javascript solution.  If i delete those attributes it doesnt work at all. And ive tried making the parent div the canvas and applying 100% blah blah doesnt work. ty tho.

Comment: Thank you :) I assumed `CSS` would be alright because of the tag.

Comment: Can I ask you an un-related question about CSS?

Comment: So im trying to get the background of this slider to be transparent. I put an animated smoke effect behind it but cant for the life of me figure out how to make the background of the slider transparent or any other color! I just want it to cycle the text. I have blank png files in there right now which ill add elements into later but just want the smoke to show. I have tried everything in dev tools, etc. Any idea?

https://portalbuild.myshopify.com/?key=2ab79d64ab05911ae9750b55a0727ca8331655b98e283a8198a3a6cc27c08a75

Comment: Aww snap the link doesnt work unless you log in. I donno what to do. Ima about to get fired. bleh.

Comment: Can you give me the `id` or `class` of the slider in question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103224/discussion-between-ivan-modric-and-portal-zii).

Comment: Okay thanks so much! I just replied and noticed your message

Comment: I'll look at the css soon.